# What could cause the blower of a Coleman furnace to come on all by itself?

Tags: furnace, gas

I have a Coleman furnace in my mobile home.  It was really hot today and the  furnace blower came on all by itself.  It has ran for 7 hrs. and wont shut off.  How do I fix this and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an HVAC person but the blower is many times controlled by a relay that can get stuck in the "on" position. If the only thing that turns the blower off is shutting off the breakers, I suspect that is the issue. Typically not an expensive repair.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter had the same problem and it randomly started blowing cold air. It was same brand I double wide suppose to be nonfunctioning but surprise. Thermostat was nailed to wall so I lossened it and was able to move the dial back and forth and it went off. I believe it is set to kick on at a predetermined temperature but it is mafunctioning.